# Mysql Query need to optimize

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-5.7, subquery, data

I have below query having proper indexes (all columns in where clause), But still query is very slow.

Can anyone help me to optimize this mysql query?

```
SELECT
        centerID,
        compID,
        SUM(points) AS points
    FROM
        (
            SELECT psd.centerID, sp.compID, SUM(psd.points) AS points FROM `puser_scoring_data` AS `psd` INNER JOIN `scoring_puser` AS `sp` ON `sp`.`id` = `psd`.`scoring_puser_id` WHERE `psd`.`scoring_date` BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31' AND `sp`.`compID` IN ('text_a_044', 'text_a_0BE', 'text_a_120', 'text_a_133', 'text_a_169', 'text_a_199', 'text_a_1E4', 'text_a_1FB', 'text_a_274', 'text_a_28C', 'text_a_2D7', 'text_a_315', 'text_a_356', 'text_a_370', 'text_a_3BE', 'text_a_3C2', 'text_a_3F4', 'text_a_412', 'text_a_4A9', 'text_a_4AA', 'text_a_4D1', 'text_a_5A7', 'text_a_5B7', 'text_a_5CC', 'text_a_62B', 'text_a_6D8', 'text_a_70A', 'text_a_733', 'text_a_804', 'text_a_851', 'text_a_8FF', 'text_a_99D', 'text_a_9A8', 'text_a_9FC', 'text_a_A0F', 'text_a_A53', 'text_a_A64', 'text_a_A9E', 'text_a_AAA', 'text_a_AD7', 'text_a_B41', 'text_a_B51', 'text_a_B5B', 'text_a_B8E', 'text_a_B96', 'text_a_BAA', 'text_a_BEC', 'text_a_C7C', 'text_a_CA4', 'text_a_CA7', 'text_a_D41', 'text_a_D7D', 'text_a_E25', 'text_a_E47', 'text_a_E49', 'text_a_EB1', 'text_a_EC4', 'b_1017', 'b_102E', 'b_1068', 'b_1071', 'b_108C', 'b_108E', 'b_1100', 'b_1125', 'b_113D', 'b_1188', 'b_11A1', 'b_11AB', 'b_11C4', 'b_1262', 'b_1286', 'b_12AB', 'b_12D8', 'b_12EE', 'b_1396', 'b_139E', 'b_14A7', 'b_14AE', 'b_14BD', 'b_1525', 'b_152D', 'b_1555', 'b_1563', 'b_1588', 'b_158E', 'b_15D7', 'b_16C4', 'b_1735', 'b_175D', 'b_1761', 'b_17F5', 'b_1807', 'b_1859', 'b_186D', 'b_1898', 'b_18F8', 'b_1A21', 'b_1A44', 'b_1A67', 'b_1BDE', 'b_1D94', 'b_1DAB', 'b_1E19', 'b_1FC9', 'b_2114', 'b_21A2', 'b_21FB', 'b_241A', 'b_2482', 'b_24CB', 'b_2594', 'b_25E4', 'b_276A', 'b_2789', 'b_27F9', 'b_2A02', 'b_2BB5', 'b_2C16', 'b_2CB1', 'b_311A', 'b_31D8', 'b_3561', 'b_356A', 'b_37D2', 'b_3821', 'b_3828', 'b_384E', 'b_387E', 'b_3881', 'b_3894', 'b_38B8', 'b_38D5', 'b_38DB', 'b_3919', 'b_3922', 'b_39CD', 'b_39EE', 'b_3AEA', 'b_3AFA', 'b_3B19', 'b_3B59', 'b_3BA5', 'b_3BF0', 'b_3C00', 'b_3C1B', 'b_3C22', 'b_3C6A', 'b_3CEA', 'b_3D22', 'b_3DF3', 'b_3E2E', 'b_3EA8', 'b_3EBA', 'b_3EF8', 'b_3F08', 'b_3F4D', 'b_3F74', 'b_3F8B', 'b_3FA7', 'b_3FAE', 'b_3FF8', 'b_3FFB', 'b_4000', 'b_406C', 'b_408F', 'b_4300', 'b_4429', 'b_44F8', 'b_4512', 'b_4548', 'b_4827', 'b_4AA2', 'b_4AF0', 'b_4B09', 'b_4CBF', 'b_4DF9', 'b_4F6D', 'b_5010', 'b_50DF', 'b_5343', 'b_5ADD', 'b_5B24', 'b_5CAA', 'b_5DE5', 'b_5EC4', 'b_5F0B', 'b_5F5A', 'b_637B', 'b_681B', 'b_6839', 'b_6889', 'b_6AB3', 'b_6B35', 'b_6B70', 'b_6C81', 'b_6E09', 'b_6FB4', 'b_7050', 'b_7320', 'b_73C3', 'b_73E3', 'b_73FA', 'b_7408', 'b_74AE', 'b_74F0', 'b_751A', 'b_76F3', 'b_7996', 'b_799C', 'b_79ED', 'b_79FE', 'b_7A3B', 'b_7A6A', 'b_7A6F', 'b_7A8C', 'b_7A90', 'b_7A91', 'b_7A96', 'b_7AC5', 'b_7AFA', 'b_7AFB', 'b_7B05', 'b_895B', 'b_8B31', 'b_8BC1', 'b_8C45', 'b_8CAA', 'b_8E88', 'b_8F1A', 'b_9229', 'b_9353', 'b_9356', 'b_9515', 'b_9568', 'b_95AA', 'b_97F4', 'b_9917', 'b_9C0F', 'b_9C5E', 'b_9E9E', 'b_9EB0', 'b_A28C', 'b_A305', 'b_A44E', 'b_A451', 'b_A7E8', 'b_B35A', 'b_B3A2', 'b_B6DB', 'b_B747', 'b_B82E', 'b_B86E', 'b_BC0E', 'b_BC71', 'b_BDDE', 'b_C0A6', 'b_C0D9', 'b_C238', 'b_C250', 'b_C304', 'b_C55A', 'b_C62D', 'b_CD8F', 'b_D001', 'b_D22E', 'b_D34C', 'b_D471', 'b_D658', 'b_D923', 'b_DA2A', 'b_DAFD', 'b_DD5A', 'b_DF34', 'b_E4F0', 'b_E54A', 'b_E56C', 'b_E75E', 'b_EEAD', 'b_F1F5', 'b_F316', 'b_F4FD', 'b_F52A', 'b_FA3B', 'b_FA90', 'b_FAB9', 'b_FF94', 'c_10135', 'c_102AF', 'c_10805', 'c_10AD4', 'c_10C0C', 'c_10CD5', 'c_10D33', 'c_10D76', 'c_10F2E', 'c_1104F', 'c_110A7', 'c_11611', 'c_1181C', 'c_11CF3', 'c_11DEC', 'c_11E93', 'c_12131', 'c_12566', 'c_1266A', 'c_12689', 'c_12A0A', 'c_12A4C', 'c_12A6E', 'c_12BD1', 'c_12C75', 'c_12E24', 'c_12EBD', 'c_13154', 'c_131EB', 'c_134A2', 'c_13586', 'c_1365D', 'c_13793', 'c_13AC9', 'c_13F3B', 'c_145C6', 'c_14861', 'c_14DD3', 'c_15395', 'c_1540E', 'c_15D9E', 'c_16CBE', 'c_16ED9', 'c_16FEA', 'c_173F9', 'c_17760', 'c_17AEA', 'c_17DE9', 'c_18137', 'c_18311', 'c_183F8', 'c_18700', 'c_1A41A', 'c_1A43D', 'c_1A5FD', 'c_1A92F', 'c_1ABA1', 'c_1B6DC', 'c_1B8FB', 'c_1BC9D', 'c_1BCCA', 'c_1BE82', 'c_1BEF4', 'c_1BF92', 'c_1C145', 'c_1CB40', 'c_1CC58', 'c_1CF1B', 'c_1D0C1', 'c_1D300', 'c_1D307', 'c_1D320', 'c_1D332', 'c_1D347', 'c_1D348', 'c_1D34E', 'c_1D350') AND `psd`.`centerID` IN (1, 2, 30, 40, 88, 90, 91, 89, 111) GROUP BY `sp`.`compID`, `psd`.`centerID`
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ps.centerID, sp.compID, SUM(ps.points) AS points FROM `puser_data_scores` AS `ps` INNER JOIN `scoring_puser` AS `sp` ON `sp`.`id` = `ps`.`scoring_puser_id` WHERE `ps`.`scoring_year` IN (2021, 2021) AND `sp`.`compID` IN ('text_a_044', 'text_a_0BE', 'text_a_120', 'text_a_133', 'text_a_169', 'text_a_199', 'text_a_1E4', 'text_a_1FB', 'text_a_274', 'text_a_28C', 'text_a_2D7', 'text_a_315', 'text_a_356', 'text_a_370', 'text_a_3BE', 'text_a_3C2', 'text_a_3F4', 'text_a_412', 'text_a_4A9', 'text_a_4AA', 'text_a_4D1', 'text_a_5A7', 'text_a_5B7', 'text_a_5CC', 'text_a_62B', 'text_a_6D8', 'text_a_70A', 'text_a_733', 'text_a_804', 'text_a_851', 'text_a_8FF', 'text_a_99D', 'text_a_9A8', 'text_a_9FC', 'text_a_A0F', 'text_a_A53', 'text_a_A64', 'text_a_A9E', 'text_a_AAA', 'text_a_AD7', 'text_a_B41', 'text_a_B51', 'text_a_B5B', 'text_a_B8E', 'text_a_B96', 'text_a_BAA', 'text_a_BEC', 'text_a_C7C', 'text_a_CA4', 'text_a_CA7', 'text_a_D41', 'text_a_D7D', 'text_a_E25', 'text_a_E47', 'text_a_E49', 'text_a_EB1', 'text_a_EC4', 'b_1017', 'b_102E', 'b_1068', 'b_1071', 'b_108C', 'b_108E', 'b_1100', 'b_1125', 'b_113D', 'b_1188', 'b_11A1', 'b_11AB', 'b_11C4', 'b_1262', 'b_1286', 'b_12AB', 'b_12D8', 'b_12EE', 'b_1396', 'b_139E', 'b_14A7', 'b_14AE', 'b_14BD', 'b_1525', 'b_152D', 'b_1555', 'b_1563', 'b_1588', 'b_158E', 'b_15D7', 'b_16C4', 'b_1735', 'b_175D', 'b_1761', 'b_17F5', 'b_1807', 'b_1859', 'b_186D', 'b_1898', 'b_18F8', 'b_1A21', 'b_1A44', 'b_1A67', 'b_1BDE', 'b_1D94', 'b_1DAB', 'b_1E19', 'b_1FC9', 'b_2114', 'b_21A2', 'b_21FB', 'b_241A', 'b_2482', 'b_24CB', 'b_2594', 'b_25E4', 'b_276A', 'b_2789', 'b_27F9', 'b_2A02', 'b_2BB5', 'b_2C16', 'b_2CB1', 'b_311A', 'b_31D8', 'b_3561', 'b_356A', 'b_37D2', 'b_3821', 'b_3828', 'b_384E', 'b_387E', 'b_3881', 'b_3894', 'b_38B8', 'b_38D5', 'b_38DB', 'b_3919', 'b_3922', 'b_39CD', 'b_39EE', 'b_3AEA', 'b_3AFA', 'b_3B19', 'b_3B59', 'b_3BA5', 'b_3BF0', 'b_3C00', 'b_3C1B', 'b_3C22', 'b_3C6A', 'b_3CEA', 'b_3D22', 'b_3DF3', 'b_3E2E', 'b_3EA8', 'b_3EBA', 'b_3EF8', 'b_3F08', 'b_3F4D', 'b_3F74', 'b_3F8B', 'b_3FA7', 'b_3FAE', 'b_3FF8', 'b_3FFB', 'b_4000', 'b_406C', 'b_408F', 'b_4300', 'b_4429', 'b_44F8', 'b_4512', 'b_4548', 'b_4827', 'b_4AA2', 'b_4AF0', 'b_4B09', 'b_4CBF', 'b_4DF9', 'b_4F6D', 'b_5010', 'b_50DF', 'b_5343', 'b_5ADD', 'b_5B24', 'b_5CAA', 'b_5DE5', 'b_5EC4', 'b_5F0B', 'b_5F5A', 'b_637B', 'b_681B', 'b_6839', 'b_6889', 'b_6AB3', 'b_6B35', 'b_6B70', 'b_6C81', 'b_6E09', 'b_6FB4', 'b_7050', 'b_7320', 'b_73C3', 'b_73E3', 'b_73FA', 'b_7408', 'b_74AE', 'b_74F0', 'b_751A', 'b_76F3', 'b_7996', 'b_799C', 'b_79ED', 'b_79FE', 'b_7A3B', 'b_7A6A', 'b_7A6F', 'b_7A8C', 'b_7A90', 'b_7A91', 'b_7A96', 'b_7AC5', 'b_7AFA', 'b_7AFB', 'b_7B05', 'b_895B', 'b_8B31', 'b_8BC1', 'b_8C45', 'b_8CAA', 'b_8E88', 'b_8F1A', 'b_9229', 'b_9353', 'b_9356', 'b_9515', 'b_9568', 'b_95AA', 'b_97F4', 'b_9917', 'b_9C0F', 'b_9C5E', 'b_9E9E', 'b_9EB0', 'b_A28C', 'b_A305', 'b_A44E', 'b_A451', 'b_A7E8', 'b_B35A', 'b_B3A2', 'b_B6DB', 'b_B747', 'b_B82E', 'b_B86E', 'b_BC0E', 'b_BC71', 'b_BDDE', 'b_C0A6', 'b_C0D9', 'b_C238', 'b_C250', 'b_C304', 'b_C55A', 'b_C62D', 'b_CD8F', 'b_D001', 'b_D22E', 'b_D34C', 'b_D471', 'b_D658', 'b_D923', 'b_DA2A', 'b_DAFD', 'b_DD5A', 'b_DF34', 'b_E4F0', 'b_E54A', 'b_E56C', 'b_E75E', 'b_EEAD', 'b_F1F5', 'b_F316', 'b_F4FD', 'b_F52A', 'b_FA3B', 'b_FA90', 'b_FAB9', 'b_FF94', 'c_10135', 'c_102AF', 'c_10805', 'c_10AD4', 'c_10C0C', 'c_10CD5', 'c_10D33', 'c_10D76', 'c_10F2E', 'c_1104F', 'c_110A7', 'c_11611', 'c_1181C', 'c_11CF3', 'c_11DEC', 'c_11E93', 'c_12131', 'c_12566', 'c_1266A', 'c_12689', 'c_12A0A', 'c_12A4C', 'c_12A6E', 'c_12BD1', 'c_12C75', 'c_12E24', 'c_12EBD', 'c_13154', 'c_131EB', 'c_134A2', 'c_13586', 'c_1365D', 'c_13793', 'c_13AC9', 'c_13F3B', 'c_145C6', 'c_14861', 'c_14DD3', 'c_15395', 'c_1540E', 'c_15D9E', 'c_16CBE', 'c_16ED9', 'c_16FEA', 'c_173F9', 'c_17760', 'c_17AEA', 'c_17DE9', 'c_18137', 'c_18311', 'c_183F8', 'c_18700', 'c_1A41A', 'c_1A43D', 'c_1A5FD', 'c_1A92F', 'c_1ABA1', 'c_1B6DC', 'c_1B8FB', 'c_1BC9D', 'c_1BCCA', 'c_1BE82', 'c_1BEF4', 'c_1BF92', 'c_1C145', 'c_1CB40', 'c_1CC58', 'c_1CF1B', 'c_1D0C1', 'c_1D300', 'c_1D307', 'c_1D320', 'c_1D332', 'c_1D347', 'c_1D348', 'c_1D34E', 'c_1D350') AND `ps`.`centerID` IN (1, 2, 30, 40, 88, 90, 91, 89, 111) GROUP BY `sp`.`compID`, `ps`.`centerID`
        ) AS t
    GROUP BY
        compID,
        centerID
```

Comment: Please add the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information on how long it takes to run to your post. Your problem is likely your huge `IN` predicate in the `WHERE` clause. You should change that to a `JOIN` to a temp table or a `UNION ALL` for each value or every few values, but that's probably going to be a lot of `UNION ALL`s.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: sure, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Are the IN lists the same?

Comment: Is the `scoring_date` sometimes not in the `scoring_year`?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table used.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, IN list is same. scoring date and scoring year are in different tables.

Comment: @Madhura - If there are no cases where the "year" differs from the "date", then remove the "year" test.